# Change type of dataframe column variable that has multiple formats

Tags: python, pandas, variables, types

I merged two datasets to the dataset "results".

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("output_apu_stock1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("Angebote_Master_File.csv")
results = df2.merge(df1,on="sku", how="left")
```

I replaced afterwards some missing values for "price_y" by the values of "price_x".

```
results['price_y'] = results['price_y'].combine_first(results['price_x'])
```

The type of the variable (price_x and price_y) have different styles and both are formatted as strings. For instance, in row 1, the variable "price_y" has the value "11,40" and in row 2, "price_y" has the value "9.9".

Potentially, it is a good idea to change the type of column variable "9.9" to "9,90" before merging the two datasets.

I tried it with

```
pd.to_numeric(results["price_y"])
```

but it does not work.

The type of the column variable "price_y" has to be a float with two digits.

Consider, the digit seperator is a european "," comma.

Comment: something like `results["price_y"].str.replace(",", ".").to_numeric()` assuming no other commas

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(results["price_y"].str.replace(",", "."))`  or `results["price_y"].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)`